# Using Table to build a matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am completely new to Mathematics. I am doing an exercise which requires me to use `Table` to make a $10 \times 10$ matrix with numbers $1,2,...,10$ on the diagonal and $1$ in the upper diagonal entries and with $0$ in the lower diagonal matrix.

I have been able to generate the diagonal command along with the upper diagonal command (using `If`) but that yields $1$ in the lower diagonals also.

Can anybody help me with this code?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: Certainly, nested `If`s or a `Which` can help here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Henrik Schumacher points out in a comment to the question, `Which`, which can be considered a multi-test version of `If`, can be used to solve your problem. Like so.

```
m = Table[Which[i == j, i, i < j, 1, True, 0], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

You could also use nested `If` expressions.

```
m = Table[If[i == j, i, If[i < j, 1, 0]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}];
```

Answer (score 3):

One using `Switch` and another using nested `If`:

```
m1 = Table[
   Switch[Positive[i - j], True, 0, False, 1; i], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 
    10}];
m2 = Table[
   If[i - j == 0, i, If[i - j > 0, 0, 1]], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}];
```